# chrome not taking max-width of columns "col-lg-9"

Tags: html, css

chrome is not taking max-width of "col-lg-3"  and "col-lg-9" and taking width 100%.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
<table class="col-12 form_one">
  <tr>
    <td class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
      <h4>Project Information</h4>
    </td>
    <td class="col-lg-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9">
      <h4>Project Text .....</h4>
    </td>
  <tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't see any problems, looks like col-md-9 is taking 75% and col-md-3 is taking 25% max-width

Comment: its perfect for firefox but not working in chrome...

Comment: this coding show 80% in chrome and remaining left for the other td

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to use a table and a grid system at the same time?

I would suggest you either use a table (which a would never recommend for layout purposes) or a grid system with more semantically appropriate elements like:

```
<section class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <h4>Project Information</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9">
    <h4>Project Text .....</h4>
  </div>
</section>
```

Also notice how you forgot to wrap your columns in a `.row` element.

See this on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/fabioioio/pen/wPJQQL)

I hope it helped :)

Comment: Hey fabio.... thanks...
but its a big table format... thats why i have to use table only....else i would also prefer section only....

Comment: so i have to use table only...as it is a big form and  for demo i have share 1st lines only...

Comment: Mhh I still think you can just use div’s as you are not showing data in a table..

Comment: If you REALLY need to use a table I'd suggest not to use the column classes then..